# Is there a word that means "structure and function"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Structure and function" is a fairly common pairing of words used in structural biology; is there some word that means the same as the both?

I've taken to using "anatomy and physiology"—"structure and function" applied to the macroscopic—but I feel that it requires some poetic license.

Comment: *[Physiomorphology](https://www.google.com/search?q=physiomorphology&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)* apparently refers to function and form, but may be too uncommon a word for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a biologist, but it seems to me *structure and function/anatomy and physiology* covers more or less everything in the field.

[Here are over 8000](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22the+biology+of+the+ear%22&pbx=1&oq=%22the+biology+of+the+ear%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4937l6875l6l7609l3l3l0l0l0l0l141l344l1.2l3l0&fp=1&biw=1238&bih=829&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b) instances in Google Books for *"the biology of the ear"*, and [over 45,000](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20biology%20of%20the%20liver%22&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for *"the biology of the liver"*. I'd be pretty sure they're all about the structure/function of those organs.

TL;DR: *"anatomy and physiology"* is **biology**.

Comment: Perhaps *"physics"* for me, as I'm using *"structure and function"* from a relatively cold, sterile viewpoint

Comment: On the contrary, structure and function are built on the base of physics.

Comment: @Nick T: Well, I'm not a physicist either, but I must admit *the physics of [some organ/organism]* more strongly suggests just the *physical structure*. And outside the realm of biology, I'd probably classify the "function" of anything inanimate as *metaphysics*. In general I think "function" implies "purpose", which doesn't mean much without living things, but *physics* is the study of what reality *actually is*, rather than *why it is so*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm actually trying to get away from a "purpose" suggestion as I'm referring to purely the mechanism.

Comment: @Nick T: I'd have thought *anatomy and physiology* would fit the bill if you don't fancy just *biology*. But if you want a really rare word that should still be comprehensible on first encounter to most people working in the field, jwpat7's *physiomorphology* should do you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, structure and function means everything except unorganized matter and energy. That makes the informational side/part of an item as opposet to the material one. And of course, any synonyms could be used - information, organization, system ... I think, it is rather filosophical question. (of course, English too)